# how do I customize my dataframe index while keeping them auto incrementing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

This is my source code:

```
Pokemon = ['Charmander', 'Bulbasaur','Squirtle','Pikachu','Eevee','Mankey']
Lvl= [10,10,10,12,10,12]

Poke_info = list(zip(Pokemon,Lvl))

Poke_df = pd.DataFrame(Poke_info, columns=['Pokemon','Lvl'])
```

This is my Output:

```
Ouput:  Pokemon        Lvl
       ------------------
    0   Charmander    10
    1   Bulbasaur     10
    2   Squirtle      10
    3   Pikachu       12
    4   Eevee         10
    5   Mankey        12
```

I want the index column named "PokeID" and the index having a string and an auto incrementing number along with it that starts from 1 like so:

```
Ouput: PokeID    Pokemon        Lvl
       ----------------------------
        P1       Charmander    10
        P2       Bulbasaur     10
        P3       Squirtle      10
        P4       Pikachu       12
        P5       Eevee         10
        P6       Mankey        12
```

How can I perform this?
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See pandas [`.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```
Poke_df.set_index('P' + (Poke_df.index + 1).astype(str)).rename_axis('PokeID')
```

returns

```
           Pokemon  Lvl
PokeID                 
P1      Charmander   10
P2       Bulbasaur   10
P3        Squirtle   10
P4         Pikachu   12
P5           Eevee   10
P6          Mankey   12
```

Comment: Is it possible to have that index column be displayed as "PokeID" too without creating a new column?

Comment: @TheDodo Yep using `.rename_axis`... Updated the answer.

Comment: Wow. this is beautiful. Thank you very much!